# How to extract the total of a column from a csv file in bash?

Tags: html, database, bash, csv

I'm currently having a problem getting the total of a column with numbers from a csv file in BASH.

Here's what I did:

```
echo "<html><body><table><tr><th>gender</th><th>Total</th></tr><tr><td>*</td><td>*</td></tr></table></body></html>" > sss.html
```

I want to extract the details from a seperate csv file with columns: box_office and subject_sex and title to get the total, gender and title of movie. the problem is I can't get the total with two gender with the same movie title add the box office for both the gender and finally display the aggregate total to the user in the above echo command.

Also, the CSV file looks like this:

[image]

Please help as I don't know how to proceed now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a CSV file, it's a spreadsheet.

Comment: Could you upload a copy of the .csv, and maybe provide an example result?